# Is it Possible to Make PDFs hosted in a Document Library not Downloadable

Tags: sharepoint-online

On our Office 365 tenant, we have a site with a document library. Is it possible to make some PDF documents not downloadable? So far I'm seeing the answer is no, but I'm soliciting any ideas.

I see View Only permissions only apply to doc types with server-side file handlers. PDF is not one of those as far as I know. Also cannot set Offline Client Availability to No since this should affect only specific documents, not the whole site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must tell you that per my knowledge, currently, this is Possible for all Office types but sadly not possible for PDF documents.

You have known this limit. I used to try to find a workaround for this  but failed.

Comment: I figured this was the case, but wanted to ask the question as a sanity check - thank you!